# ANOVA with small sample (duplicate)

Tags: anova, mean, sample

I have a study with only a duplicate sample. I would like to know if there are differences between the 5 averages, each group has two samples.
In another case, I have 3 averages and each group has 3 averages in the same case, two samples. Can I take the ANOVA test? I auditioned for Lillie and Hartley and everything is fine.
In the research area where I do the study it is common to have duplicates, due to the cost.

The analysis is about an application in the biotechnology area. Comparisons between glucose measurements in different enzymes

Comment: Can you edit to expand on what exactly your data layout is? At the moment it is not quite clear. Also note that _to audition_ means to go through a trial to be an actor in a play or other performance so I think you need another word there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The analysis is about an application in the biotechnology area. Comparisons between glucose measurements in different enzymes

Comment: although it is already 3 yrs after your question, may I know if you did 2-way-ANOVA with only duplicate data?
thank you !